# How to Load Multiple Instance for the dynamic dll in mfc

Tags: dll, mfc

I was wondering is there a way to load multiple instances of a DLL explicitly (i.e. with LoadLibrary call). Normally, a process loads a DLL just once when LoadLibrary is called (so that a single copy of the library resides in the process' memory) and all consequent calls of LoadLibrary done for the same library would be returning just the same handle of the library, returned by the very first call. To be more specific, I want to be able to load a separate instance of a DLL for each thread created inside of a process. Currently, if I do LoadLibrary in each thread, I just get the same pointer to a single instance of the library residing in the process' address space, and all threads in fact refer to the same functions from the library (here a big mess occurs in my app). Instead, I want each thread to create an individual instance of the library in a separate memory space so that the threads don't interfere with each other when calling functions from the library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that is possible (until you create a new process and load the DLL in that process). DLLs are loaded at the process level (hence have entries in Process control block). Although your DLL can detect if new thread is created in the host application so that it can initialize TLS specific data in DLLMain method.

Comment: Ankur :Can you give some sample for your explanation?

Comment: You can refer to DllMain documentation at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682583(v=vs.85).aspx . Specially the remarks section

Comment: Ankur: my objective is to create many instances for the same dll.

Comment: It won't be possible. By the way why you want to do this?

Comment: Ankur: My application needs this. I have one global variable in my dll.for the particular scenario ,two of my dll names are same.At that time I have to separate that variables.

Comment: You will have to remove that global variable and rather use thread local storage variable so that each thread get a specific variable in the DLL to play with. Global variables are really a bad design

Comment: Sorry Ankur, My application is already designed like that.During enhancement,I came across this issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4481/discussion-between-karthik-and-ankur)